# Can we configure settings.xml to our own location in maven

Tags: maven, maven-3

Recently I am working with Apache Maven in Windows machine.
I am executing maven from **Command Prompt** every time.

I know that MAVEN will pick its `settings.xml` from `C:\Users\abc\.m2\settings.xml`

**Question**: Can't I change this `settings.xml` to be picked from my own provided location instead of default location, like `C:\Users\abc\.m2\settings.xml`

That is, instead of `C:\Users\abc\.m2\settings.xml` location I will configuring it in `F:\myFolder\settings.xml`.

If so, what are the steps I need to follow and check?

Comment: Your question has actually two questions, you should remove the second part and create a different question for it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the location of user settings using the `-s` option from the command line:

> `-s,--settings <arg>`     Alternate path for the user settings file

You could hence invoke Maven as following:

```
mvn clean install -s F:\myFolder\settings.xml
```

---

If you don't want to specify it at each and every invocation, since Maven [**3.3.1**](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-5767) you can specify a `.m/config` folder in your project folder and a `maven.config` file in it providing this option.

The `.m/config/maven.config` file would have in your case the following content:

```
-s F:\myFolder\settings.xml
```

And it will be applied to all Maven invocation for that project.